# Two seemingly analogous cases of using Kirchhoff's current law to calculate current through a node

Tags: circuit-analysis, current, kirchhoffs-laws

I'm currently studying the textbook *Fundamentals of Electric Circuits*, 7th edition, by Charles Alexander and Matthew Sadiku. Chapter **2.4 Kirchhoff's Laws** has the following practice problems:

> Find current \$i_o\$ and voltage \$v_o\$ in the circuit shown in Fig. 2.25.
> [image]
> **Solution:**
> Applying KCL to node \$a\$, we obtain
> $$3 + 0.5 i_o = i_o \ \Rightarrow i_o = 6 \ \text{A}$$
> For the \$4 \ \Omega\$ resistor, Ohm's law gives
> $$v_o = 4 i_o = 24 \ \text{V}$$

> Find \$v_o\$ and \$i_o\$ in the circuit of Fig. 2.26.
> [image]
> **Answer:** \$12 \ \text{V}, 6 \ \text{A}\$.

For Figure 2.26, it seems to me that \$i_o\$ is the current through the node above the \$2 \ \Omega\$ resistor. This node has a \$9 \ \text{A}\$ current flowing into it and a \$0.25i_o\$ current flowing out of it. Therefore, by Kirchhoff's current law, we have that \$9 \ \text{A} - 0.25i_o = i_o \ \Rightarrow i_o = 7.2 \ \text{A}\$. But this is incorrect. So what am I doing wrong here? This problem seems to be analogous to the previous one, so I don't understand what's different (besides the additional branch).

Comment: The KCL is easy: \$\frac{V}{2}+\frac{V}{8}+0.25\cdot\frac{V}{2}=9\:\text{A}\$. This trivially solves out as \$V=12\:\text{V}\$. Ground the bottom wire. Then this is just: *"The current **out** of the \$2\:\Omega\$ resistor, plus the current **out** of the \$8\:\Omega\$ resistor, plus the current through the dependent current source equals \$9\:\text{A}\$"*.

Comment: Look over your own work, compare it with mine, and tell me where you went wrong.

Comment: Let's assume that the lower node is called \$V_{_\text{A}}\$ and the upper node is called \$V_{_\text{B}}\$ and that the voltage difference between them is \$v_o=V_{_\text{B}}-V_{_\text{A}}\$ per their definition.

Comment: Then \$i_o=\frac{V_{_\text{B}}-V_{_\text{A}}}{2\:\Omega}\$ and these two KCL statements: \$\frac{V_{_\text{B}}}{2\:\Omega}+\frac{V_{_\text{B}}}{8\:\Omega}+0.25\cdot i_o=\frac{V_{_\text{A}}}{2\:\Omega}+\frac{V_{_\text{A}}}{8\:\Omega}+9\:\text{A}\$ and \$\frac{V_{_\text{A}}}{2\:\Omega}+\frac{V_{_\text{A}}}{8\:\Omega}+9\:\text{A}=\frac{V_{_\text{B}}}{2\:\Omega}+\frac{V_{_\text{B}}}{8\:\Omega}+0.25\cdot i_o\$. These solve out as \$i_o=6\:\text{A}\$ and \$V_{_\text{A}}=V_{_\text{B}}-12\:\text{V}\$. You can assign anything you want to either \$V_{_\text{A}}\$ or \$V_{_\text{B}}\$. But only one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The major issue in your attempted solution is that you are in no way taking into account the current through the 8 Ohm resistor. Remember that current into a node must equal the current out of a node. Summing currents at the top node, we have:
$$9 = \frac{v_o}{2} + 0.25 \cdot \frac{v_o}{2} + \frac{v_o}{8}$$
where
$$i_o = \frac{v_o}{2}$$
This quickly simplifies to:
$$9 = \frac{3 \cdot v_o}{4}$$
At which point solving for current and voltage becomes trivial. Hopefully this clarifies things

Comment: Where is the assumption \$i_o = v_o/2\$ from?

Comment: @ThePointer It comes from Ohm's Law. Why do you think it is an assumption rather than an expression resulting from such a simple law? Don't you see that the same voltage across the 8 Ohm resistor must also be exactly the same across the 2 Ohm resistor, too?

Comment: @jonk Oh, so they're using the \$2 \ \Omega\$ resistor to find \$i_o\$ using Ohm's law?

Comment: @ThePointer Yes!! In a sense, anyway.

Comment: I'm confused about the \$8 \ \Omega\$ resistor. By Ohm's law, wouldn't we have that \$v_o = 8 i_o\$? But this implies that \$i_o = \dfrac{v_o}{8} \not= \dfrac{v_o}{2}\$. We just used Ohm's law for the \$2 \ \Omega\$ resistor, so I don't understand why we wouldn't do the same with the \$8 \ \Omega\$ resistor.

Comment: @ThePointer No, because *io* doesn't flow through the 8 ohm resistor. What makes you think it does? Just think about it. If *io* flows through the 2 ohm resistor then the *vo* = 2 * *io* and this is also the voltage across the 8 ohm resistor. Hence the current through the 8 ohm resistor will be *vo* / 8 = *io* / 4

Comment: vo is the voltage across the 8 ohm resistor. Since 2 ohm and 8 ohm are in parallel, they have same voltages, so V(8 ohm) = V(2 ohm) = current through 2 ohm * resistance = 2io = current through 8 ohm * resistance. Hope it helps.